# NiFi: ReplaceTextWithMapping processor

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have the following insert statements:

1. `insert into temp1 values (test1, test2)`
2. `insert into temp2 values (test3)`

Expected results:

1. `insert into temp1 values (100, 200)`
2. `insert into temp2 values (300)`

Essentially, I wanted to replace the first query literals `test1`, `test2` with value `100`, `200` respectively and for the second query replace `test3` with value `300`. Can someone help with the mapping file for the above use case?

I tried with the following, but it doesn't have any effect.

Search Value (RegEx) Replacement values

```
(1)(.*values.*)(.*test1)(.*,)(.*test2) -> $2 val1 $4 val2

(2)(.*values.*)(.*test1) -> $2 val3
```

Comment: Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is literally the extent of the mapping you need to perform, a regular `ReplaceText` processor is enough. Using the settings below results in the desired output:

[image: ReplaceText configuration]

It simply detects every instance of `test` followed by a single digit and replaces it with that digit and `00`.

If you need to use `ReplaceTextWithMapping` for more complex lookups, the mapping file must be of the format:

```
search_value_1    replacement_value_1
search_value_2    replacement_value_2
etc.
```

The delimiter between the search and replacement values is **\t**.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Wed Dec 07 10:48:24 PST 2016'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Wed Dec 07 10:48:24 PST 2016'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '66'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '56196144045589'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: 'f6b28eb0-73b5-4d94-86c2-b7a5d4cc991e'
--------------------------------------------------
insert into temp1 values (100, 200)
insert into temp2 values (300)
```