# Update the values in a field inside the CSV using NiFi

Tags: apache, etl, apache-nifi

I want to achieve a simple use case to update the multiple string/Text values to an Integer value in a field inside a CSV using NiFi. For Example, my CSV file looks like:

**Input CSV File:**

**Field_1, Field_2**

America, Apple

America, Apple

India, Grapes

China Town, Orange

Australian Nation, Peach

India, Grapes

China Town, Orange

So I want the output CSV to be like:

**Input CSV File:**

**Field_1, Field_2**

1, Apple

1, Apple

4, Grapes

3, Orange

2, Peach

4, Grapes

3, Orange

I want all the America in Field_1 to be updated to 1 and Australian Nation to 2 and China Town to 3 and so on...I was able to update just one value using **UpdateRecord processor** as using the replacement Value Strategy as "**Literal replace**". Please see the attached picture below:

[image: UpdateRecord Processor]

But I am not able to update the remaining values like China, India etc in Field_1. I know that I can replicate multiple UpdateRecord processors to achieve this But I want to achieve this use case with one processor only. How can I do this using one processor? If yes, what configuration to set in NiFi to achieve this?
Thank you in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Shu Can I not achieve this using UpdateRecord processor? Also using this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876754/replace-string-value-to-integer-value-in-nifi-within-a-same-column/ would make me write all the columns present in the CSV. For example, I have 1000+ column and I only want to update Field_1 so How would be the case statement for that? should i do select *, Case statements? I am confused here

Comment: @Shu or can I achieve this with ReplaceText? If yes how? THanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`QueryRecord`** processor (using Sql like case when statement)

(or)

**`LookupRecord`** processor by defining **`SimpleKeyValueLookupService`**

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876754/replace-string-value-to-integer-value-in-nifi-within-a-same-column/) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/113845/how-to-use-simplekeyvaluelookupservice-processor-i.html) links for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ReplaceTextWithMapping`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceTextWithMapping/) processor can perform this operation. It reads a "lookup" file which contains the value mappings and performs a line-by-line replacement. Here is [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41025174/70465) which has example configuration values. It's not "record-oriented", but should work for the scenario you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly. Can you help me with the Regex for my use case? I am not sure how to define the regex for my case.

Comment: Based on the provided input, I would try something like `^([\w\s]+)(?=\s?,)`. That will match "word(s)" at the start of a line followed by (optional) space and a comma. You may have to play around a bit with the capture groups to align with the key/value pairs in the lookup file. Provenance data and log output for the processor will be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

On the field definition do another replace.

```
${field.value:replace("America","1"):replace("India","4"):replace("Australia","2")}
```

etc.

That worked for me