# Add column to csv using predefined file using apache nifi

Tags: csv, validation, apache-nifi

I get a raw csv file which looks like this

```
id,name,star
1,sachith,2
2,nalaka,1
3,abc,3
```

I want to map star column with another file where it has

```
1  1S
2  3S
3  5S
```

and finally csv should look like

```
id,name,star,level
1,sachith,2,3S
2,nalaka,1,1S
3,abc,3,5S
```

I have used [ReplaceTextWithMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156066/update-the-values-in-a-field-inside-the-csv-using-nifi), but it replaces all the 1,2,3 values including in id column.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156066/update-the-values-in-a-field-inside-the-csv-using-nifi) it defines replacing a value, but I want to map and add a new column to the record.

Edit:

After @Upvote's answer. My ReplaceTextWithMapping conf
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**ReplaceTextWithMapping**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceTextWithMapping/). Overall flow:

[image]

GenerateFlowFile:

[image]

UpdateRecord:

[image]

Configure `CSVReader` to treat first line as header. Leave other properties untouched. Configure `CSVRecordSetWrite` to treat first line as header, schema to be derived from schema text property and set schema text to:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"foobar",
   "namespace":"my.example",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"name",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"age",
         "type":"int"
      },
      {
         "name":"id",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"nick",
         "type":"string"
      }
   ]
}
```

Notice that it includes the new column. ReplaceTextWithMapping:

[image]

Mapping file content:

```
1   1S
2   3S
3   4S
```

Values are separated by tab. Regex must match the last value not followed by a comma in each line:

```
[0-9](?!,)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/V7e092JAX2ISmjP7)

Result:

[image]

Comment: When I follow these steps, final result row looks like `1,sachith,2,2`, where final 2 should be 3S.

Comment: @Sachith you have to replace ,2 with ,3S. Use ReplaceTextWithMapping or ReplaceText as described in the linked answer.

Comment: Yes, I used `ReplaceTextWithMapping` processor. But final result same.

Comment: Share your ReplaceTextWithMapping config.