# Apache NiFi: Mapping a csv with multiple columns to create new rows

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, data-processing

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553048/add-column-to-csv-using-predefined-file-using-apache-nifi) on stack overflow. This approach worked fine with just a couple of columns But I realised this method is not possible for csv's with a large number of Columns.

I have a csv with 75 columns. I decided to follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553048/add-column-to-csv-using-predefined-file-using-apache-nifi) (Same link as mentioned above). As asked to do in that question. I added the `UpdateRecord` processor and added the `CSVReader` and `CSVWriter`. Then as told I entered my `SchemaText`. **Which was pretty long as it required me to define the entire 70 columns.** Then `CSVRecordSetWriter` was told to be `invalid`.

**I realised after a *certain number of column definitions* I included in the schema it became `invalid`.**

Part of my schema looks like this:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"test2.csv",
   "namespace":"my.namespace",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"download",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"upload",
         "type":"string"
      }
      .
      .
      .
      .
      {
         "name":"operatorId",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"errorCode",
         "type":"string"
      }      
   ]
}
```

Also my csv contains headers.

**Objective**:
I need to map the data in the `errorCode` Column to a new column named `errorMean`. Hope you can suggest a method I can achieve this. Fell free to give a solution which can even completely skip the process of writing down the `Schema Text`.

Comment: Hey Himsara, have you tried doing the same, but saving the schema to an AvroSchemaRegistry? I can't test without having access to your full schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a similar question on stack overflow. This approach worked
>   fine with just a couple of columns But I realised this method is not
>   possible for csv's with a large number of Columns.

To avoid providing a very large schema, you set the `CSVReader's` `Schema Access Strategy` to `Infer Schema` and `CSVRecordSetWriter's` `Schema Access Strategy` to `Inherit Record Schema`. So when the CSV is read, the schema will be inferred. The same schema will then be used to write the CSV.

[image]

The rest of the mapping works the same as described in the answer you linked.

Comment: The 'Inherit Record Schema' schema access strategy simply tells any RecordSetWriter to use the schema that the RecordReader used, therefore it does not necessarily mean that it will get it from the CSV header.

Comment: @IanNeethling thanks Ian! I corrected that in my answer.

Comment: @Upvote then the processor isn't said to be invalid but it replaces all the values in every column. I only want to to replace the values in the new column.

Comment: @HimsaraGallege most likely your regex is wrong. Please provide the regex and and example input.